# How to get user city name location by permission and than send that city name location to backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How to get user city name location by permission and than send that city name location to backend? How can i do this thing in my code? in react native expo and Nodejs

Backend:

```
router.post('/updateCity', (req, res) => {
  const city = req.body.city;
  const username = req.body.username;

  User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: username }, { city: city }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'City updated successfully'
    });
  });
});
```

Frontend:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>App</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using expo module [Location](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/location/) with this method [Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location, options)](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/location/#locationreversegeocodeasynclocation-options)

```js
location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ accuracy: 1 });
if (location) {
  const geocodedAddress = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(
    {
      latitude: location.coords.latitude,
      longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    }
  );
  console.log(geocodedAddress.city)
}
```

Comment: i am new to rn it would be much helpful if you can give me a full code so that i can just copy paste and use it my backend api is working fine in postman but its not working wth rn Can you give me full code?

Comment: @wdwd I know nothing about your backend, this is an example of a hook which contains all you need to work with location https://github.com/jonelofficial/metro-gps_offline/blob/a620da71396f5fa708b0528d09a31798f84a6ff1/app/hooks/useLocation.js

Comment: i have given my backend code in my quastion